# Angular MongoDB Problems Adding Product to Cart

Tags: html, angular, mongodb, express

Hello I'm creating a an e-commerce site. I am having a couple of issues. I tried resolving this myself but I still get the same outcome..

when I add to cart for a userId  and cart does not exit for that user I can  create a cart but  none of the properties show only the id.

Note: Per the http request I do try to add to cart by by passing product id.

This is the request:

```
 product: {_id: "651352899db20fb85059c210", name: "Pink To Slick",
 size: "S",…}
 description: "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and 
 typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy 
 text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type 
 and scrambled it to make a type specimen book."
 imageUrl: "http://localhost:4200/assets/PinkToSlick.png"
 name: "Pink To Slick"
 price: 299
 size: "S"
 _id: "651352899db20fb85059c210"
```

This is the response after creating cart for new user

```
 {
    "_id": "658b9124f6176ca87b91ab6f",
    "userId": "6588baa65a346036b4479398",
   "product": [
    {
        "_id": "651352899db20fb85059c210"
    }
  ],
"active": true,
"modifiedOn": "2023-12-27T02:51:16.211Z",
"createdAt": "2023-12-27T02:51:16.243Z",
"updatedAt": "2023-12-27T02:51:16.243Z",
"__v": 0
}
```

Here is My Schema for CartItem

```
var express = require('express');
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Products      = require('../backend-search/Products.cjs');
const User = require('../../app/backend/users/user.model')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;    

module.exports = mongoose.model("item", ItemSchema);


 const cartitemSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   userId: {
     type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
     ref: "User"
    },

  product: [ 
  {
  _id:{
    type:String
  },

 name:{type:String},

 size:{type: String}, 

 imageUrl:{ type:String},

price:{type:Number},
    
}],
  
  


  active: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: true
  },
   modifiedOn: {
   type: Date,
   default: Date.now
  }
 },

 { timestamps: true },

);

  module.exports = mongoose.model('Cartitem', cartitemSchema, 'cartitems');
```

Here is the snippet add to cart:

```
     router.post('/getProducts/addtocart:_id',   async(req, res)=>{


      const { name, size, imageUrl, price} = req.body

       _id = req.params._id; 


      userId =({"_id" : ObjectId("6588baa65a346036b4479398")})  
        //hardcoded for now

        //logically I'm thinking I have to get the product from products 
          collection

       mongoose.connect(mongoURI, function(err, db){
         db.collection('products').findOne({"_id" : ObjectId(_id)},( 

         function (err, result) {
         console.log('findOne callback');
         if (err) throw err;

         console.log("Results"  +  "" + result);  //object object
 

          }));
      })

         //Logically  I'm thinking I need to get the data of products 
            and add to cart.  I' stuck here


          //Adding a cart for user because one does not exist
       else{

       //no cart for user, create new cart

         let newCartitem  =  Cartitem.create({
            userId,
            product: [{_id:_id,
            name, size, imageUrl, price
           }]  
    
        });

               return res.status(201).send({newCartitem});


         }//end of else

   } catch (err) {
     console.log(err);
     res.status(500).send("Something went wrong");
 }      

})

      Note I started off with fake backend on client side which every thing 
      works, now I'm strickly on back end. I can load products, delete when 
      I add fake data to the cart. The application will add to shopping 
      cart  and increment count but there is no data; Can someone please 
      point me in the right direction I have been working trying to 
      resolve this  fix this for some days. I'm missing some time

      [![Shopping Cart][1]][1]
```